# How to close browser after creating C# WebClient class?

Tags: c#, webclient

I provide an HTTP web service and one of my users is using C# WebClient class on a Windows 2003 machine to retrieve data from my website.  My user says that WebClient is creating many browser instances and needs to be closed.  How can he close the browser after it's created?

His code:

```
Byte[] requestedHTML;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
requestedHTML = client.DownloadData("http://abcabc.com/abc");
UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
string returnMessage = objUTF8.GetString(requestedHTML);
```

*p.s. Apologies if this sounds amateur, I'm very new to C#.*

Comment: Please don't apologies. We all here for learning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WebClient` *does not use a browser* - it it just a wrapper around the underlying protocol. You *should* add a `using`, but this has nothing to do with "many browser instances":

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    return client.DownloadString("http://abcabc.com/abc");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **WebClient** class in the .NET Framework holds onto some system resources which are required to access the network stack in Microsoft Windows. The behavior of the CLR will ensure these resources are eventually cleaned up.

However, if you manually call `Dispose` or use the `using-statement`, you can make these resources be cleaned up at more predictable times. This can improve the performance of larger programs.

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    // Do your operations here...
}
```

You can refer this beautiful tutorial: http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient

Comment: If I could, I would also give credit to you as you posted the same answer almost immediately after Marc Gravell.  :)